# How to use iptables to get access to regionally unavailable server?

Tags: iptables, forwarding

My goal is to get access from a client app located in Country A that tries to reach out to its server located in Country B while country A blocks access to country B servers. Pretty easy, just to create Ubuntu server in country C.

A mobile client with a dynamic IP sends packets to an intermediate server, which should forward all traffic to the blocked one, and can be done by command, but will it keep client's IP as the source so that server will know the clients real IP?

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.1:1234
```

How to forward incoming traffic from server 1.1.1.1 back to client's original IP? This one is suitable:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 1.1.1.1 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I wpuld use a vpn for this.  The above commands should work if the intermediate box is set up to forward packets. (is ip_forwardung on?).  The first command does DNAT which rewrites the source address - ie packets received by B will see the packets as coming from the intermrdiate server and will teply to that.  The intermediate server will rewrite the replies and send back to A

Comment: 1.1.1.1 is a public DNS server but the port is 53 -> Please dont use other real IP adresses to obfuscate your IPs...